# Finding "hotspots" in unidimensional list in python

Tags: python, sorting, clustered-index

Given a list of pairs of unidimensional coordinates (or segments) like the next:

```
[1]: 1200, 1210
[2]: 1212, 1222
[3]: 1190, 1200
[4]: 300, 310
...
[n]: 800, 810
```

(where you can take the center of each pair to represent each element)
I want to know what algorithm or what kind of algorithm can I use in order to find "hotspots" or clusters.

A hotspot is a segment containing certain amount of items in it (let's say k).

For example [3], [1] and [2] would belong to the same group and the resulting list would be something like:

```
[1']: 1190, 1222 ([1], [2], [3])
```

(begin, end, contained elements)

Comment: Define your problem more precisely. What is a hotspot? Without a good mathematical definition, how do you now that "put everything into one group" or "put everything into a separate group" is not a correct or optimal solution? State the problem like "divide `n` segments into `k` disjoint sets so that ... is minimized".

Comment: that's a good start. I think I have to minimize the distance between segments, but still not sure how to explain it more precicely

Comment: "put everything into a separate group" minimizes distance between segments just perfectly. Until you have a constraint or a better cost function, there is not much help you can get.

Comment: well that's not what I'm trying to do. I know I'm not being precise but I think you can understand me

Comment: It's always a difference of 10 between the left and right columns?

Comment: there is a difference of n, being n always the same for each set of data

Comment: You probably need to read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not really well-defined, but maybe this will help you.

KMeans is a way of clustering items by distance. Scikit-learn has an implementation, that is quite easy to use. See http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_digits.html#example-cluster-plot-kmeans-digits-py for an example.

This will allow you to define the numner of clusters you want to find. You cannot however know how many points will end up in each cluster. Anyway, here's a small example:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

data = [[1200, 1210], [1212, 1222], [1190, 1200], [300, 310], [800, 810]]
centers = [[sum(x) / len(x)] for x in data]

clf = KMeans(n_clusters=3)

clf.fit(centers)

for points in data:
    center = sum(points) / len(points)
    print points, center, clf.predict([center])
```

Output:

[1200, 1210] 1205 [1]

[1212, 1222] 1217 [1]

[1190, 1200] 1195 [1]

[300, 310] 305 [0]

[800, 810] 805 [2]

EDIT: Another algorithm provided in SKLearn is Affinity Propagation, that doesn't require the number of clusters to be set before hand. I don't know how this exactly works, but you should be able to find some info on that yourself.

Example:

```
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
import numpy as np

data = [[1200, 1210], [1212, 1222], [1190, 1200], [300, 310], [800, 810]]
centers = np.array([[sum(x) / len(x)] for x in data])

clf = AffinityPropagation()


for (points, cluster) in zip(data, clf.fit_predict(centers)):
    center = sum(points) / len(points)
    print points, center, cluster
```

Output:

[1200, 1210] 1205 0

[1212, 1222] 1217 0

[1190, 1200] 1195 0

[300, 310] 305 1

[800, 810] 805 2

Comment: excellent, is there any way to modify this algorithm to automatically determine the number of clusters?

Comment: with this dataset the results are not consistents data = [[4944, 4964], [4946, 4966], [4935, 4955], [4942, 4962], [4947, 4967], [4934, 4954], [4941, 4961], [4945, 4965], [4940, 4960], [4943, 4963], [4941, 4961], [4935, 4955], [4930, 4950], [4935, 4955], [4936, 4956], [4940, 4960]]

Comment: Well, what is not consistent? It seems to find two clusters with a cut off point around a center of 4950. That seems reasonable given the data and the fact that the algorithm has no knowledge of what it represents. Maybe if you have some more info on what the actual problem is? You might be able to leverage that.